# How to convert php array into javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have tried to implement PHP array into JavaScript but the problem is that it is not converting properly.

For example if PHP array `$new_array` has a value of `a,q,s,t,u` it is assigning to all the indexes of JavaScript array for example:

```
js_array[0]=a,q,s,t,u;
js_array[1]=a,q,s,t,u;
js_array[2]=a,q,s,t,u;
js_array[3]=a,q,s,t,u;
js_array[4]=a,q,s,t,u;
js_array[5]=a,q,s,t,u;
```

This is my PHP code:

```
    $new_array = array(); // create a new array
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animate ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5") or die("query Field");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $new_array[] = $row['code'];

 }
```

js code

```
var array =[<?php echo json_encode($new_array);?>];
        alert(array[0]);
   for(var i=0; i <=9 ; i++)
        {
            array[i]=[<?php echo json_encode($new_array);?>];
    }
```

I want to assign values like:

```
array[0]=a;
array[1]=q;
array[2]=s;
array[3]=t;
array[4]=u;
```

I want to do in this pattern but it is not working.

Comment: What is in `$row['code']`???

Comment: `[<?php encode ?>]` is creating an array with your encoded array in it, which you then store in ANOTHER array.  all you need is `var arr = <?php echo json_encode($your_array); ?>`;

Comment: can you answer the question @MarcB with a proper code

Comment: not working @MarcB

Comment: not workin g**HOW**? Like I said, if you just want to embed that array of values you built in php to a var in javascript, then ALL you need is the one line I posted above. everything is just creating a bigger array with multiple copies of your from-db array in each element.

Comment: I think you may wish to look up Javascript's comma operator. I think `js_array[0]=a,q,s,t,u;` is not doing what you think it is doing

Answer (score 4):

You could "implode" it or you could use JSON.

#### Implode Method

```
var array = [<?php echo implode($array, ","); ?>];
```

#### JSON Method

```
var array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the php array inside the js array braces.

```
var array =[<?php foreach ($newArray as $value) echo "'" . $value . "',"; ?>];
```

You might have to put an additional line to clip the last `,`